# Regex split into words and punctuation/symbols

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following input:

```
func add(var a:Int, var b:Int) -> Int
{
    return a + b
}
```

I'm using this Regex `\s*\b\s*` which I found online which is supposed to split up words and punctuation/symbols. I tried it and it split up the input to

```
func
add
(
var
...
```

Which is working exactly how I want it to, until it finds the `->` sign, where it outputs

```
:
Int
) ->
...
```

Everything else works fine but I would like it to output

```
)
-
>
```

instead.

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which regex flavor are you interested in?

Comment: A word boundary `\b` is found between a word character `\w` and a non-word character `\W`. You won't find a word boundary between 2 non-word characters, so you'll need to be a little more explicit about which characters should be group and which should be split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't exactly know which version of regexp you are using and which command you are running to verify it I can't be completely sure that this solves your problem, but it should.

```
\s*(\b|[->])\s*
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. @cmbuckley told me that I won't find a word boundary between 2 non-word characters. This means that I will have to add all non-word characters that may be placed next to each other inside the `[]` for them to be separated, correct?

Comment: Won't that remove the `->` characters from the output? Again, depends on the flavour of regex. @Ignaus please can you update the question? Is this a PHP question?

Comment: @cmbuckley I tested it and it was included in the output

Comment: So it's not a PHP question then. What type of question is it? Please tag the question so that it may be of use to others!

Comment: @Ignaus yes you can just simply add more characters inside `[]` but as @cmbuckley already said, I'm also intrigued how you actually tested the code.

Comment: @cmbuckley I'm using a Windows program called Expresso to test it, so I'm guessing .NET or C++